# Invalid negative value for <image> attribute width="-3364.67"

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, bootstrap-modal

I use `Raphael JS library` and i have some errors in Chrome an Safari

**Invalid negative value for element attribute -value**

```
Error: Invalid negative value for <image> attribute width="-3364.67" (index):1
Error: Invalid negative value for <image> attribute height="-3364.67" (index):1
Error: Invalid negative value for <image> attribute width="-3364.6662980435035" (index):1
Error: Invalid negative value for <image> attribute height="-3364.6662980435035" (index):1
Error: Invalid negative value for <image> attribute width="-3364.6662980435035" raphael.js:6153
Error: Invalid negative value for <image> attribute height="-3364.6662980435035" raphael.js:6175
Error: Invalid negative value for <image> attribute width="-3364.6662980435035" raphael.js:6153
Error: Invalid negative value for <image> attribute height="-3364.6662980435035" raphael.js:6175
```

Maybe someone has such a situation and could suggest me something.

THX in advance

The prombelem is in Raphael.js on line ~ 6153 and 6175

```
               case "width":
                    node.setAttribute(att, value);
                    o._.dirty = 1;
                    if (attrs.fx) {
                        att = "x";
                        value = attrs.x;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
```

and

```
               case "height":
                    node.setAttribute(att, value);
                    o._.dirty = 1;
                    if (attrs.fy) {
                        att = "y";
                        value = attrs.y;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
```

Comment: Would you give us a working example that produces these errors?

Comment: Yes. I do it. 
1. Video fot understunding http://youtu.be/l4-L51IlCI0
2. Link for exemple http://map.elitiv.com/v7/

Try it in Chrome/Safari and Firefox for diference

Comment: Can you create a reduced testcase, the smallest possible amount of code that shows the problem?

Comment: is it resolved or provide simple example what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Not solved yet. i can't provide simple example quikly. But, the problem is here: case "width":
                        node.setAttribute(att, value);
                        o._.dirty = 1;
                        if (attrs.fx) {
                            att = "x";
                            value = attrs.x;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
Line 6153 in raphaerl.js. The same for height

Comment: What exactly is `value`, that you set here?

Comment: Error: Invalid negative value for <image> attribute width="-3364.6662980435035" raphael.js:6153
Error: Invalid negative value for <image> attribute height="-3364.6662980435035"

Comment: Can be checked at the http://map.ombudsman.md/  click on any region and sea in console (Chrome browser)

Comment: The error originates in getScale() function in mapsvg.js, returning a negative value, and is *probably* due to a wrong calculation, but I haven't investigated it more. But you probably know that already.

Comment: **Big picture**: How can Raphael draw a negative `width` value? It's like asking "Build me a box with height: 2in, width: **-5in**, depth: 10in". Issue doesn't like with Raphel, it's the image itself.